# Header in a panel with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, header, width, panel

I'm stuck with this problem: i want to put a header widget in a panel widget with jquery mobile and i want that the headers width is equal to the panel width.

My code is here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vthbgko/)

```
<body>
<a href="#userPanel">&gt;&gt;</a>

<div data-role="panel" id="userPanel" data-display="overlay">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" class="ui-nodisc-icon" class="navbarPanel">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="" data-icon="user" class="navbarPanelBtn">User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-icon="mail" class="navbarPanelBtn">Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-icon="power" class="navbarPanelBtn">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, the navbar doesn't cover the full size of the panel. How can i remove that space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Right now in your CSS you have `1em` of padding on `.ui-panel-inner`.  Try removing that and it should cause the navbar to cover the full size of the panel

Comment: Thank you Michael, it works. But now some pixels of the third button are shown outside the panel, here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/0vthbgko/1/